# PivotCaches.Add Mismatch Error - Why didn't it happen before?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, pivot-table

I am getting a mismatch error 13 when running the code below. The whole code module has been in use and mostly unchanged for over a year, I haven't changed anything recently, and I am the only user of this workbook.

**Non-working code:**

```
Private Sub CreateMIAPivots(MIABook As Workbook, MIASheet As Worksheet, MaxRow As Long)

Dim wksPivotSheet As Worksheet
Dim PivotRange As Range

    Set wksPivotSheet = MIABook.Sheets.Add
    wksPivotSheet.Name = "Summary"
    wksPivotSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    Set PivotRange = MIASheet.Range("A1:Y" & MaxRow)
    With MIABook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PivotRange) 'Error sets here
    'More code below
```

`MaxRow` is variable, but I've checked it against a file with about 600 to about 7,000 rows, and the `Range` object is making a valid reference if I try to interact with it any other way.

I have reviewed some related questions here on SO:

- [I am only working in 2003, and the error is different, anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854203/698590)
- [I have confirmed I have no other `PivotCaches` in the workbook before attempting to create a new one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8450450/698590)
- [I have successfully gotten this work using the accepted solution here:Use named ranges (see follow-up code below)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10423071/698590)

**Work-around code:**

```
Private Sub CreateMIAPivots(MIABook As Workbook, MIASheet As Worksheet, MaxRow As Long)

Dim wksPivotSheet As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim lVBAVer As Long
Dim PivotRange As Range

    lVBAVer = CLng(Application.Version)

    Set wksPivotSheet = MIABook.Sheets.Add
    wksPivotSheet.Name = "Summary"
    wksPivotSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    Set PivotRange = MIASheet.Range("A1:Y" & MaxRow)

    MIABook.Names.Add Name:="PivotRange", RefersTo:=PivotRange

    'Using answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868231/698590 (StackOverflow) 
    'as a guide for version checking. Original answer of 
    'CLng(Application.VBE.Version) did not work here.
    #If lVBAVer <= 11 Then
        Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "PivotRange")
    #Else
        Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "PivotRange")
    #End If
    With pc
    'More code below
```

My question is now *why* is the above solution necessary? It appears that I am not the only one who has had perfectly working code suddenly stop while using `PivotCaches` like I had initially. So what is the real root cause here? What caused the code to stop functioning?

I'd like to know so, if possible, I can prevent future unexpected errors from arising. I know that the answer may lie in something I did somewhere else in the code/workbook (not referenced here), but I can't for the life of me track down what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you already know the problem is related to this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/pivotcache-type-mismatch-error-when-65536-rows/0827889e-b671-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=4e3a2b20-7a72-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

The reason appears to be that the VBA syntax/usage of pivot tables was changed from 2003 to 2007/2010.

So it uses this common syntax to set a named range in the workbook with this:

```
MIABook.Names.Add Name:="PivotRange", RefersTo:=PivotRange
```

This section of code:

```
#If  lVBAVer <= 11 Then 
    Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "PivotRange") 
#Else 
    Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "PivotRange") 
#End If
```

Is checking to see if the lVBAver is less than or equal to 11, if is less - then it uses this syntax:

```
Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, "PivotRange")
```

If it is the new version then it uses this syntax:

```
Set pc = MIABook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "PivotRange")
```

Sometimes you just have to accept that Microsoft is not perfect(lol irony) and they do stupid things just like every other company. That is my theory anyways. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @stepan1010, but this isn't exactly my issue. I did come across the program version check while I was looking for a solution, but I am only using Excel 2003. I included the check on my own for possible future upgrading. What seems to be the correct solution is the named ranges. While the named ranges work, it does not make sense that directly calling the range (a la `Sheet.Range("A1")`) stopped working with no other apparent changes to the code.

Comment: I don't know if this bit of information will help you at all but my understanding was that the problem you are having was not just due to the version of excel you are using but the version of VBA you are using. It appears CLng(Application.Version) does give you the application version - not the VBA version. But I still think the problem might be specific to the version of VBA you have not the version of the application. That is my suspicion at least based on what you told me about only using excel 2003 during this problem. So perhaps you udpated what version of VBA you are using at some point.

Comment: How does one update the VBE version without updating the Office  application? Regardless, if I try the VBA7 version (`.Create`), I am given an error saying that is not a valid member of `PivotCaches`. Again, I do get the code to work with the VBA6 syntax (`.Add`), but I must use named ranges instead of directly referencing the range I want, though I've never needed to do this before.

Comment: Yea, well, then I am at a loss. Syntax doesn't just change overnight. There must be something you changed or some kind of update to the application or VBA that you downloaded. But, that is the limit of my understanding as of right now.